# How to send queries to database with fixed delay

Tags: java, concurrency

I am trying to query a database with a list of message ids to get back the message metadata and aggregate the result into a map. The database have the limitation regarding the read tps and throughput so I plan to perform the reads with a fixed one second delay. Below is the implementation I did.

The problem with the implementation is

1. The queries are sent out sequentially and a single query could take a long time. So the delay indeed becomes (query time + 1s sleep). But I would start the second query one second right after the first query is sent.
2. When some exceptions are thrown, I would like to re-throw it and let the caller of the method to handle the exception. The current implementation force me to catch the exception and handle it within the map.

Would like some recommendation about an implementation which does not have the above two problem

```
public PollingResult pollMessagesMeta(final List<Long> messageIdList) throws InterruptedException {
    Map<MessageMeta, Integer> messageMetaCountMap = new HashMap<>();

    Map<MessageMeta, Integer>result =
            messageIdList.stream().map(messageId -> new MessageMetaFetcher(messageId))
                    .map(MessageMetaFetcher -> {
                        try {
                            return MessageMetaFetcher.call();
                        } catch (ServiceException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)));
}


    private class MessageMetaFetcher {
        private final Long messageId;
        MessageMetaFetcher(Long messageId) {
            this.messageId = messageId;
        }

        public MessageMeta call() throws ServiceException, InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            final MessageMeta messageMeta = new MessageMeta(
                    Database.getMessageStatus(messageId),
                    Database.getMessageContent(messageId));
            return messageMeta;
        }
    }
```

Comment: executor service, schedule at fixed rate

Comment: dont use .map(). create a new function, do a for each loop, then call MessageMetaFetcher.call(); add the result to your Map<,> result, or throw the exception

Comment: @Michael ScheduledExecutorService only works with Runnable and the overriden run method does not allow me to rethrow the exception.

Comment: @Charles for loop does not solve the delay problem since it's every query is sequential.